# Android : User input from hardware key not working

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application that uses a `WebView` and an `EditText` field.
When I  display the login page for Facebook, it works absolutely fine.
The page is loading  perfectly fine but i am not able to type anything inside login information.

I have already set different options for my webview:

```
myview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

But none of them solved my problem.

This problem is not specific while loading  facebook.
Even for google search , i am not able to type anything in search bar.

In logcat, error is coming as:

```
﹕ onEvaluateInputViewShown: config.hardKeyboardHidden = 1
```

I wonder why this error is coming as I am able to type  inside the Edittext field .

Any ideas what might be the issue ?

Comment: Hi, did u find any solution to this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                   if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                       v.requestFocus(); 
                   } 
                   break; 
           } 
           return false; 
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
I am able to select username/password field , they already  have input focus flashing in blue color but typing in them does not work.  
There is no problem with focus i guess.
Ps: i have already tried solution given by you , but sadly my issue is not solved.